# What type of soil for transplanting bamboo?

Tags: houseplants, container-gardening, transplanting, potting-soil

Do you need special soil to transplant bamboo? Also, do you have to keep it in water or can you use potting soil? I have tried regular potting soil, but the bamboo died.

Comment: No, no need for special soil - if you used new potting soil, that shouldn't have caused a problem, assuming the pot you used had drainage holes and was more or less the right size.. Can you provide  more information, such as which bamboo is it (if you know), whether you're trying to keep it indoor or outdoor, where you are in the world - and a photo  of the plant concerned would be very helpful.